# How do you dodge a horizontal linerange in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

How do you dodge a `ggstance::geom_linerangeh` in `ggplot2`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstance)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarize(lo = mpg %>% min,
            hi = mpg %>% max) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_linerangeh(aes(y = am %>% 
                    factor,
                  xmin = lo,
                  xmax = hi,
                  group = am %>% 
                    factor),
              position = position_dodgev(height = .25)) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 1)
```

results in :

[image]

whereas I would like to see the lines sitting slightly below the horizontals, consistent with the standard behaviour of `position_dodge` elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get dodging, you need to map colour or linetype to another variable that splits `am` into sub-categories based on that third variable; otherwise there's only one category for each level of `am` and therefore nothing to dodge.

For example, let's use `vs` as that other variable and we'll map it to color. We also add rows (using `complete`) for missing combinations of `am`,`vs`, and `cyl` to ensure that dodging occurs even for combinations of `cyl` and `am` where only one level of `vs` is present in the data.

```
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs=factor(vs), cyl=factor(cyl), am=factor(am)) %>% 
  summarize(lo = mpg %>% min,
            hi = mpg %>% max) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(am, cyl, nesting(vs)) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_linerangeh(aes(y = am, colour=vs, xmin = lo, xmax = hi),
                    position = position_dodgev(height = 0.5)) +
    facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 1) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `group=vs` if you want though.

Comment: Yes, although then the lines for different levels of `vs` will be indistinguishable.